# 100% width (of page) drop down/drawer menu with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I've been stuck trying to figure out how to code a menu much like what you see on the Playstation website: http://us.playstation.com/

**EDIT**: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjcarlson/7q64A/

So far I have a number of issues. The first is that I have been unable to create the 100% width, because, I am assuming, of the parent/child relationship.

The second issue I have is that my Timeout works on all class elements rather than only the currently hovered element. In other words, if all elements have slid down and one is hovered over, they all will remain open until none of them have been hovered for 1.5 seconds. I admit that my inability to come up with a solution may be due to my limited experience with the language. Below is the CSS:

```
.accordion-container {
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.accordion {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 15px 35px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.accordion-question {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #06F;
    background-color: #9F0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-answer-container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #999;
    background: #F00;
}

.accordion-answer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #0C0;
}
```

Then, the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.accordion-answer')
    var timeout = 0;
    var hovering = false;
    menu.hide();

    $('.accordion-question').hover(function () {
        hovering = true;
        // Open the menu
        $(this).closest('.accordion').find('.accordion-answer')
            .stop(true, true)
            .delay(400).slideDown(600);

        if (timeout > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
        resetHover();
    });

    $('.accordion-answer').hover(function () {
        hovering = true;
        startTimeout();
    })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
        resetHover();
    });

    function startTimeout() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            closeMenu();
        }, 1500);
    };

    function closeMenu() {
        if (!hovering) {
            $('.accordion-answer').stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
        }
    };

    function resetHover() {
        hovering = false;
        startTimeout();
    };
});
```

And finally, the HTML:

```
<div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-question">
            <h2>Is this a question?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-answer-container">
            <div class="accordion-answer">
                <p>To be honest, I am not sure</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>List item one</li>
                    <li>List item two</li>
                </ul>
                <p>That is all.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /accordion -->
    <div class="accordion" id="testanchor">
        <div class="accordion-question">
            <h2>What would be a good second question?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-answer-container">
            <div class="accordion-answer">
                <p>I don&rsquo;t know, man!</p>
                <p>That is all.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /accordion -->
</div>
```

Styling is minimal right now (sorry) as I'm just trying to get this figured out. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Fiddle made. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

To get a width of 100% you should not display them as *inline-block* and set the width of *.accordion* to 100%.

In the hover-event you set *hovering* to *true*. If the next hover-event occurs prior to the call of *closeMenu*, then the if clause will already be *false*.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the .accordion to 100% will not result in the menu format as you see in the example Playstation site, which is the layout I'm trying to achieve. I want only the drop down submenu to achieve the 100% width, with the top level menu item (.accordion) inline with its siblings. Perhaps my structure is off. CODROPS has something at least similar to what I'm looking to do: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalDropDownMenu/

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish the 100% width of your dropdown by altering the css of your `.according-answer-container` to a `fixed` position along with setting `left` and `right` to 0:

```
.accordion-answer-container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #999;
    background: #F00;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[An update to your fiddle shows this working](http://jsfiddle.net/D7pXL/)